# How to prevent multiple entries of the same db? and sqlite3 now wont execute?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import sqlite3
import array
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random
pygame.init()

f=pygame.font.SysFont(None,60)

class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        Label1 = Label(root,text = "Username")
        Label2 = Label(root,text = "Password")
        self.Entry1 = Entry(root)
        self.Entry2 = Entry(root,show = "*")

        Label1.grid(row=0)#default column is 0
        Label2.grid(row=1)

        self.Entry1.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
        self.Entry2.grid(row = 1,column = 1)

        root.minsize(width = 300,height = 80)
        lgbutton = Button(text = "Login",command = self.ButtonClicked)
        lgbutton.grid(columnspan = 2)


    def ButtonClicked(self):
            username = self.Entry1.get()
            password = self.Entry2.get()
            GetDatabase(username,password)#compares the username and password to the ones stored in the database

def GetDatabase(username,password):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('TEST.db')
    c=conn.cursor
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentLogin(surname TEXT, username TEXT, password INT);")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TeacherLogin(surname TEXT, username TEXT, password INT,class TEXT);")
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO StudentLogin (surname,username,password)
VALUES
    ('Fred', 'Smith',123),
    ('John', 'Tucker',123),
    ('Michael', 'Jefford',123),
    ('Robert', 'Thomas',123);''')            
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO TeacherLogin(surname,username,password,class)
VALUES('Tucker','HTucker',123,'12C/C1'),
('Cooper','ACooper',142,'12C/Ma1'),
('Smith','KSmith',1223,'12C/Ch1'),
('Elston','FElston',454,'12C/Ch1');''')
    StudentUsername=[]
    StudentPassword=[]
    TeacherUsername=[]
    TeacherPassword=[]


    c.execute("SELECT * FROM TeacherLogin;")
    for column in c:
        TeacherUsername.append(column[1])
        TeacherPassword.append(column[2])

    print(TeacherUsername)
    print(TeacherPassword)

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM StudentLogin;")
    for column in c:
        StudentUsername.append(column[1])
        StudentPassword.append(column[2])
    print(StudentUsername)
    print(StudentPassword)


    c.execute("DROP TABLE TeacherLogin;")
    c.execute("DROP TABLE StudentLogin;")

    if username in StudentUsername:
        correct=int(StudentUsername.index(username))
        if int(password) == StudentPassword[correct]:
        #if password in Password :
            tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome "+username)
            root.destroy()
            Simulation()
    elif username in TeacherUsername:
        correct=int(TeacherUsername.index(username))
        if int(password)==TeacherPassword[correct]:
            tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome "+username)
            root.destroy()
            TeacherLogin()
    else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username or password")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def TeacherLogin()
    pass

def StudentLogin():
    pass        

root=Tk() #creating blank window
root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
root.title("Please login.")
root.minsize(width=300,height=80)
Login()
root.mainloop()
```

At the moment I've written some code that allows the user to enter their username and password which will then compare their details to the ones in the database. It worked before, but now in comes up with the error of:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Why does it now not execute?

Also, I'm quite new to sqlite3 and I'm wondering how to only insert the values into the db if they're not there as currently it has to drop the values in the table in order to stop them from being repeatedly added each time someone logs in incorrectly. As I don't want the db to be full of the same values.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `c = conn.cursor()` instead of `c = conn.cursor` `GetDatabase`.

As for the duplicates, when you design your table, you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint to a column or set of columns. This will automatically reject duplicates from the database.

Comment: How would I do this? How would the data then be checked if it is already in the database?

Comment: When you create a table you can specify that a field (column) be constrained to unique values with something like `CREATE TABLE t1(a, b UNIQUE);`. If you want a constraint to an existing table it's a bit more tricky with SQLite. Documentation for both can be found here. https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to **call** the cursor method.

```
# ...
def GetDatabase(username,password):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('TEST.db')
    c=conn.cursor() # Call this one!
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentLogin(surname TEXT, username TEXT, password INT);")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TeacherLogin(surname TEXT, username TEXT, password INT,class TEXT);")
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO StudentLogin (surname,username,password)
#...
```